# How to configure the target in a new systemd service

Tags: systemd

I've to configure a new service file for systemd using. I would like to know if we can put serveral taget in the same line of the line `after` like the example below or I've to create a service for each run level

Example :

```
[Unit]
Description=New service 
After= runlevel2.target runlevel3.target runlevel4.target runlevel5.target
```

I don't know if I need any separator among other things

The old service has a chkconfig like this :

```
chkconfig: 2345 91 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The `chkconfig` line is arguments for `update-rc.d`, which takes three positional parameters: the list of runlevels to start in, and the start and stop priorities -- so this is not a list of things that are interchangeable.

Systemd does not use runlevels, so when translating to a systemd service this is difficult to map exactly. Fortunately, pretty much everyone uses `2345` or `345` as runlevel configuration, and direct translations of those exist:

- Runlevels 2-5 in the default configuration are multi-user runlevels (i.e. user logins are permitted), so this translates to `multi-user.target`.
- On distributions where runlevels 2 and 3 differ by default, runlevel 3 starts the X server, while runlevel 2 doesn't. If you see `345`, which is rather seldom, that translates to `graphical.target`.

The targets are then referred to in `WantedBy=` lines, e.g. `WantedBy=multi-user.target`.